# Does the SSL/TLS lifetime change affect client certificates?

Tags: authentication, certificates, x.509, client-side

From 2020.09.01 Google, Apple an Mozilla changed the maximum trust time to 398 days. I'm working on a project, where the client also authenticates itself with a certificate. This certificate is stored in the browser. So does this change affect the lifetime of the client certificate, or only the server side? Can my private CA also provide certificates longer than 1 year?